# How can I customize button size of ScheduleReboot dialog?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I can customize the message of ScheduleReboot dialog using `<Error Id="1703">message</Error>`. But, how can I customize button size of the dialog?

AFAIK, the ScheduleReboot dialog's appearance varies from MSI to MSI, not all the ScheduleReboot dialogs are identical(I have two MSI's that have different ScheduleReboot dialogs in button size). That is, there must be something to edit the dialog's appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some experiments I concluded that the button size of ScheduleReboot dialog follows the button size of the *error dialog* that is set by using `ErrorDialog` attribute in `Dialog` element.

Answer (score 0):

If that button is a control in a dialog that's in the MSI file then you can edit it with a tool like Orca, the MSI editor. If you look in the Control table of the MSI file, you should be able to find the dialog and the button, with its Width and Height attributes to change. Ideally you'd change that in the source of whatever tool generates the MSI if you can.